# How to apply regex group matching on another string?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Using Python 3, I'm trying to replace a pattern group from a regex recovered from a string, to another string, for instance :

With the following regex "([a-z]+).([a-z]{3})", and the following string : "image.jpg", I'd like to replace the groups in another string, which is "Your file of type \2 has the name \1.".

This would result in a string being "Your file of type jpg has the name image."

Using `re.search`, and looping over `.groups()` by doing `destination.replace('\{pos}', current)`, but it breaks if groups has more than 9 entries. I'm hoping there is a more efficient way to do that.

As far as I know, `re.sub` applies to the same string, which is why I can't use it.

Comment: Number of back references have to match with number of capture groups in regex. How are you making sure?

Comment: Please provide a test case if the answers below do not work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#python3
import re
exp=r"([a-z]+).([a-z]{3})"
stri="image.jpg"
f= r"Your file of type \2 has the name \1."
result= re.sub(exp, f, stir)
print(result)
#output: "Your file of type jpg has the name image."
```

Comment: Ok, this is evident! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you avoid regex entirely and do something like the following:

```
inputString = "testImage123.jpg"
filename, _, ext = inputString.rpartition(".")

result = f"Your file of type {ext} has the name {filename}."
# Your file of type jpg has the name testImage123.
```